# ${1\over4}$ chance everyone looks at camera, how many pictures to guarantee at least a ${4\over5}$ chance of everyone looking at camera?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

> I'm taking pictures. For each picture, I have a ${1\over4}$ chance that everyone is looking at the camera. How many pictures must I take to have at least a ${4\over5}$ chance of having a picture in which everyone is looking at the camera?

Here's what I did. The probability is going to be$${1\over4} + {1\over4} \left({3\over4}\right) + {1\over4} \left({3\over4}\right)^2 + \ldots = 1 - \left({3\over4}\right)^n.$$So I computed some this for some $n$ by hand.

$n = 1$: $1/4$

$n = 2$: $7/16$

$n = 3$: $37/64$

$n = 4$: $175/256$

$n = 5$: $781/1024$

...all of these are less than $4/5$. At this point I gave up. Wolfram Alpha tells me that $n = 6$ is greater than $4/5$ though. Is there a quick way to eyeball or divine this without having to laboriously calculate by hand?

Comment: Solve the inequality $1-(\frac 34)^n\ge \frac 45$ i think

Comment: if you can use log table then that helps

Comment: The complement rule can help you reach the formula $1-(\frac 34)^n$ without writing everything out. It's P(at least one picture everyone look at camera) = 1 - P(all pictures not everyone looks at camera)

Comment: @EmperorConcerto: The best you can do to "divine" it is that you need $$n\ge\log_{3/4}(1-4/5)=-\log_{3/4}5=\log_{4/3}5=\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 4-\ln 3}$$ But there is no real way to avoid logarithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability of success in a Bernoulli trial, $P$ be the probability you want to reach "at least" and $n$ the number of trials. Then

$$1-(1-p)^n \geq P \qquad (1-p)^n \leq 1-P \qquad n \geq \frac{\ln{(1-P)}}{\ln{(1-p)}} \quad \to n \geq \frac{\ln{0.2}}{\ln 0.75} = 5.6 $$

So for at least $n=6$ there is at least a chance of $0.8$ that everyone is looking at the camera.